# CakePHP (2.x) modify layout based on conditions

Tags: php, layout, cakephp-2.1

Is it possible, in CakePHP v 2.x to modify the default layout (default.ctp) based on a condition - such as if a user is logged in. 
Let's assume I have a menu:

"Home" "Menu Item1" "Menu Item 2"

and I'd like to change this once a user is logged in to:

"Home" "Menu Item1" "Menu Item 2" "Menu Item 3" "Menu Item 4"

Where/How can I achieve this? I assume I'd have to call the "$this->layout('new-layout');" somewhere but I'm not sure where exactly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are too many difference between your both layout (before / after log in) than make two layout & in your AppController (in beforeFilter function) change layout if user is logged in.

```
if($this->Auth->user()){
    $this->layout = "new_layout";
}
```

And if it is just about some menu links. You can directly put condition in your default.ctp file.

```
if ($this->Session->read('Auth.User')){
 //Add more menu for logged in users.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me correctly you should be able you use the same layout an just use:

```
-- Menu Item 1
-- Menu Item 2
if ($authUser) {
  -- Menu Item 3
  -- Menu Item 4
}
```

You'll have to set the following in the controller:

```
$this->set('authUser', $this->Auth->user());
```

Been a while since I used Cake though!